# Javascript timeOut function - strange behavior

Tags: javascript

Im trying to implement a [simple blckjack game](http://venko.byethost14.com/), the problem is that the timeOut function is not working as I expect. I wrote some debugging messages to help you understand what I mean. With two words what I see is that the function is called once and than for some reason it exits from the function, program continues executing itself and than retunrs to the timeOut function...
What I want is to pause the program execution to wait user to choose whether to request new card ot to stop.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: @simonlchilds view link. http://venko.byethost14.com/

Comment: I've tryed a code proposet in this forum using the same function and it behaves the same way.

Comment: It would be more beneficial for you to post the bit of code that you think you're having trouble with, rather than expecting us to find it ourselves.

Comment: you should come out with a problem

Answer (score 0):

Where is the waitForUserInput() method being called?  Also, why use a timeout for grabbing user input?  Why not simply subscribe to the mouse click event?

Comment: waitForUserInput() is called at line 185
Im new at JS this is what i developped...

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` will not stop exection of a script. It is just for delayed execution. After you call it - execution of program will be continued as usual, but after specified time - function passed as a first parameter will be executed. To wait for user input - take a look at click/keyup/keydown etc. events.

You should not do things like below in JS. JS always single thread and such loops will just freeze your interface. In yor case it looks like you should place `onclick` event on card block and put there a code which will do what you need.

```
while(true){
        waitForUserInput();
        if(requestCard){
            userHand.hitMe();

            var userHandCards = userHand.printHand().split(",");
            displayCard(userHandCards[cardIndex]);
            cardIndex++;
            //console.log(">"+userHand.score());

            if(userHand.score()>21){
                break;
            }
        }else{
            break
        }

    };
```

> What I want is to pause the program execution to wait user to choose whether to request new card ot to stop

You should place some buttons with onclick handlers specified. And just run code you need depending on clicked button. Right now I do not see how user can say to your program about his choice.  If that is a keybord command ("s" pressed than stop, "n" - next card ) - you can try to use `document.onkeyup`.

Comment: I code in JS for only 8 days. Every proposals like these you did are helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I can't say how to make your program work. It is large enough already. But if you are so new to JS - take a look at different developer tools. Usually you can call them with F12 in any browser(except FireFox - you should install firebug extension first). You can debug your code there. And as I told - use avaiable events to get a user input.

Comment: Ok if I understand correctly I must use this: document.getElementById('request_card').onclick = ...(where requqest_card is a button) or <input id="hit_me" type="button" value="request_card"  onclick="setButtonPressed();"/>
This seems to me quite limiting and I abandoned the idea at the begining(that was one of the first things ) because I didn't succeed to embbed it into my code.

Comment: yes, that is the way you should do it. Suppose you will need to change your logic of your program a lot. `setButtonPressed` is a wrong logic. You should use something like `requestCard()` instead of it. It sound like you are trying to write JS program like with Win32 API (one entry point and loop to wait for events), but that is bad approach. JS is completely event driven and you do not need some infinite loop to make it work

Comment: Thank you. I will change the entire logic if necessary to make this program work:)

Comment: I finished the game. It works as FAngel proposed. Thank you man!